# How can I create a byte signature for ClamAV?

Tags: byte, elf, signature, antivirus

I want to get a byte sequence out of the .text section of an object file and turn it into a signature. I want to execute ClamAV's `clamscan` with this signature to find other object files containing the same byte sequence.
With objdump the byte sequence looks like this:

[image]

A byte sequence for this example could look like this:

> 55 48 89 e5 48 83 ec 10 bf 0a 00 00 00 e8 ?? ?? ?? ?? 48 89 45 f8 c9 c3

the ?? being place holder.

I didn't find a way to do it with sigtool. Is there another tool for that, or do I have to do it manually and if so in which form do I have to save the signatures (format within the signature database and format of the database itself)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to write a script which was doing this task by hand. I didn't find a way sigtool can do that for me. A script ran through the objdump and replaced the variable bytes. I stored the result in a database and with this database I could identify which library was linked statically using clamscan in binary mode (even if someone strips out the library names).